# Matlab, how can I give week number not just for a year?

Tags: matlab

I have 5-minute frequency S&P500 data from 1983~2010.
Given matrix are arraged as [date time price return].
More detail description for date and time is following:
data : yyyymmdd
time : hhmm

[image]

I want to sort given data by week number.
To be more specific, I want to tag weeknumber for each column.
I know 'weeknum' function, but just using the function has two problems 
to achieve my purpose.
One, it returns week number in a year. So, 1986.12.31 is tagged 53 and 1987.1.1 is tagged 1, although two days belong to same week.
Two, I want to cumulate the week based tag. If 1986.12.31 is tagged 53, 1987.1.1 need to be tagged with 105.

Comment: Can you get the yearnum, multiply it by 52, and add it to the weeknum?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an arbitrary starting date of 1/1/1983 (and assuming you're using the datetime variable), you would need to write a wrapper around weeknum to handle the edge cases for the January 1-4 scenarios.

The worst edge case where thee most days that the first week of January could be in the previous year's trading week would be if Dec 31st fell on a Monday and Jan 1 through 4 are Tuesday through Friday (though New Years day is a trading holiday for the S&P). Assuming again if Jan 1 is on a Monday, it's a new week, a quick and dirty example of what you would want to do is shown below

```
function weekcounter=edgecases(dateinput)
    if (month(dateinput)==1 & (day(dateinput)<4)) % only care about those first 4 days in January, otherwise weeknum works as advertised.
        if 2<weekday(dateinput)&& weekday(dateinput)<7        
            weekcounter= weeknum(dateshift(dateinput-calmonths(1),'end','month')) % make sure this matches the last day of the previous month
        end
    else
       weekcounter=weeknum(dateinput)
    end
end
```

Testing the code out shows the following

```
>> edgecases(datetime([1986 1 1]))

ans =

    53

>> edgecases(datetime([1986 1 4]))

ans =

     1

>> edgecases(datetime([1986 1 3]))

ans =

    53
>> edgecases(datetime([1987 1 3]))

ans =

     1

>> edgecases(datetime([1987 1 2]))

ans =

    53
```

Once you have computed the given week number, do what @Trogdor suggests to get the cumulative week number.

Granted this also presupposes that your date variables have trading holidays etc removed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I tried the function you made, edgecases. But it does not work well except the first year of my data. Specifically, in case of January 1984, the code work well and correct my problem but  I found some problem in case of 1985, 1986... I could not find how to modify it. Could you look in the function once more?

Comment: Be more specific as to what problems you are encountering. This function works for all the edge cases that I have seen so far (you will have to do an arrayoperation on your dates to get the week number this way.

Answer (score 0):

If inputdates is a datetime vector:

```
previousSundays = dateshift(inputdates,'dayofweek','Sunday','previous');
weekCount = findgroups(previousSundays);  % a vector of same size as inputdates
```

Comment: Please format your answer with back ticks `like so`.